# Editing/Adding records in MVC Using Jquery Dialog does not show errors from server in the Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

Here I am doing a adding, editing with jquery dialog window with the same partial view, get and post methods for both operations.
this is how i m opening my dialog on the click (Below shown dialog is for creating a new record)

```
$("#openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var url = $(this).attr('href');

                $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                    title: 'Add Student',
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 355,
                    width: 400,
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load(url);
                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                });

                $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
```

This is My partial view for loading the content to Jquery Dialog

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEditRecord", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>
    <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentID)
        @Html.ValidatioMessageFor(model =>model.StudentID)
    </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.EditFor(model => model.Name)   
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
        </div>
        <p>
            @if (ViewBag.IsUpdate == true)
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Update" id="btnUpdate" name="cmd"/>
            }
            else
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" name="cmd"/>
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Below is the Method to get the records to show in the dialog

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddEditRecord(int id?)
        {
        if(id!=null)
        {
                    Student student = db.Students.Where(m => m.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                    return PartialView("_StudentData", student);
                }
                return PartialView("_StudentData");
            }            
        }
```

Below is my Post Method on submitting the record after entering details in to dialog form 
dialog data will be posted to this method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEditRecord(Student student, string cmd)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (cmd == "Save")
      {
         try
         {
            Student student = db.Students.Where(m => m.StudentID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if(student!=null)
            {
               db.Students.Add(student);
               db.SaveChanges();
               return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
               ModelState.Error("", "Record already exists");
               return PartialView("_StudentData", student);
            }   
         }
         catch { }
      }
         else
         {
            try
             {
               Student stud = db.Students.Where(m => m.StudentID == student.StudentID).FirstOrDefault();
               if (stud != null)
               {
                  stud.Name = student.Name;
                  stud.Age = student.Age;
                  stud.State = student.State;
                  stud.Country = student.Country;
                  db.SaveChanges();
                  return RedirectToAction("Index");
               }
             }
             catch { }
         }
      }
     return PartialView("_StudentData", student);
}
```

On Submitting the Modal validation is working and showing errors on the dialog itself,
I am trying to do the same in the post when the user submits Records this will check for any duplicate StudentID in the table if there is none then the record is saved to database and redirects to the Index(list of students page). 
but if there is a record exists then i want to show to the user in the dialog that a record with same Student ID exists but the UI redirects and the dialog is shown in the parent window instead of the dialog. 
i did some research but did not get found an answer to achieve this.

Comment: use ajax form instead of html form

Comment: Tried that too but still redirecting to main window.